# How to number in a custom way

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing a latex file (format : book) and would like the subsections in the first chapter/section to be labeled as S.1, S.2 , S.3 etc. I tried to find how to do this on the net but could not. Please help.

Comment: What about the numbering for the second section/chapter? Ideally you should create what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your current issue.

Comment: Should the prefix "S." also appear in an eventual table of contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this before your first chapter:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{S.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Assuming that you want to go back to the regular numbering (section.subsection) afterwards, put this before the second chapter.

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```